# How do I convert VueJS to static HTML file?

Tags: html, vue.js, npm

I want to convert a simple VueJS file to static HTML and host it on an S3 bucket.

How can I make this conversion?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. If you only need the HTML, the `<template>` should suffice. If you also need the behavior of the component when mounted, you likely want to create an app which mounts the component, build the app and deploy the contents of `/dist` folder. If you want this app, but in the context of a bigger page (e.g: controlling only a portion of a page), you might want to look into exporting custom elements using Vue. To get appropriate help, you have to provide more context.

Comment: You might want to check https://astro.build/ which is a framework for static site generation, that also works with vue js.

Comment: Or use vues ssr: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html and safe the html output to a file